# Vertical Align a href in Safari on iPhone Issues

Tags: html, css

On IPhone on Safari, the "x" in this element is not centered like it is on web. Below is my structure and css. Any suggestion on how I can correct this?

```
<div class="notification-card" data-non-read="">
  <div class="notification-card-body"></div>
    <a href="#" data-mark-as-read-one="" data-url="report/mark-as-read?id=38634">×</a>
</div>
```

```
.notification-card [data-mark-as-read-one] {
    top: -5px;
    right: -6px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #d10e00;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Safari Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8Hmw.jpg)

I have reviewing other articles, but I have not seen this exact situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.